# Simple way to call a method on the View (Code Behind)

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, caliburn.micro

I have a small issue I was hoping somebody could help me with. I have to call the NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() on two of my views due to the way I have my first run wizard set up.

This method needs to be called on the view (in the codebehind) as far as I am aware and cannot be called in my view models.

I was wondering what would be the easiest, cleanest way to call a RemoveLastNavEntry() from the ViewModel if the method lives on the view.

Rob has said it is a feature he will build into the navigation service at some point but until then I need to implement this as a minor hack.

Comment: You could submit a pull request with the method added and I would accept it very quickly :)

Comment: @EisenbergEffect I had a look, I wasn't sure where to add it. If you can point me to the right class I will take a bash at it.

Comment: @EisenbergEffect My other worry is that this is SPECIFICALLY mango functionality.. I don't want to break anything adding mango only features to your codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this truely is a task for the view, you *can*, if you really want to, call it from the ViewModel, as a static call.

```
(App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).RemoveBackEntry()
```

See [PhoneApplicationFrame.RemoveBackEntry Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.removebackentry%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: It's not strictly but my limited understanding of how Caliburn.Micro works means I don't want to edit the source if I am not 100% sure I am doing it right, for now, your method should suffice, thanks.

Comment: To clarify I would class the navigation as part of the ViewModel functionality. The view should be dumb in my own opinion, including knowing it is in a stack of views.

Comment: Navigation is a part of the View's responsibility. That's also why you need to use it from the UI thread. I don't find that Caliburn plays nicely from when it comes to seperation of concerns. Caliburn is more a upside-down way of avoiding trivial work.

Comment: I guess we will have to agree to disagree :)